# how to condition split supporting case details information in ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

How many maximum cases are possible in conditional split Transformation in SSIS?

Comment: How many do you anticipate needing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know.

I know that using the below Biml, I was able to generate an SSIS package with a conditional split with 1024 output paths which went to their own, empty, Derived Column.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <#int upperBound = 1023;#>
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\dev2014;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Packet Size=32767;" Name="Source" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="SO_50393307">
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT CSPL POC">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource Name="SRC Query" ConnectionName="Source">
                            <DirectInput>SELECT 1 AS Col1;</DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                        <ConditionalSplit Name="CSPL Boundary Test" >
                            <OutputPaths>
                                <# foreach (int indexer in System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, upperBound)){#>
                                <OutputPath Name="Repro_<#= indexer #>"><Expression><![CDATA[Col1 == <#= indexer #>]]></Expression></OutputPath>
                                <#}#>
                            </OutputPaths>
                        </ConditionalSplit>
                        <# foreach (int indexer in System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, upperBound)){#>
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER Anchor <#= indexer #>">
                            <InputPath OutputPathName="CSPL Boundary Test.Repro_<#= indexer #>" />
                        </DerivedColumns>
                        <#}#>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Now, just because I was able to generate that package doesn't mean that Visual Studio could *edit* the package. After an hour of letting VS2017 churn on opening it, I gave up.

It does however execute - took 7 seconds from the commandline.